# Classification NN defaults to one answer - Better cost function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

[image: Distribution of NN Output]

Above picture is the distributions of a binary output from a Neural Network that I wrote. (Y-Axis is percentage of Yes output, X-Axis is iteration)

I trained a NN on a binary classification dataset that has labels 0-No, 1-Yes

However I try to change the parameters of the NN (tried different layer count, layer size, activation function) the **NN output oscillates from outputting all Zeros or all Ones.**

I am using tensorflow to build the NN with this as the cost function

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=prediction))
```

I am 90% sure that the NN is sound in term of architecture as it is the same one I used for the MNIST dataset. Also have tried many different datasets and it seems to be able to classify datasets well.

The training dataset contains 58% of No labels and 42% of Yes labels.

I have a suspicion that the feature inputted into the NN is uninformative to the NN to make a decision hence why defaulting to one answer is better for it.

I would like to know what kind of Cost function would better penalize the current behavior of the network?

Code:

```
def neural_network_model(data):
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_nodes_hl1]), name="w1", collections=["weights", tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES])
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]), name="b1", collections=["bias", tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES])

    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2]), name="w2", collections=["weights", tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES])
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]), name="b2", collections=["bias", tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES])

    wout = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_output]), name="wout", collections=["weights", tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES])
    bout = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]), name="bout", collections=["bias", tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES])

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, w1), b1)
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, w2), b2)
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)


    output = tf.matmul(l2, wout) + bout

    return output

n_input = len(features[1, :])
n_nodes_hl1 = 2000
n_nodes_hl2 = 2000
n_output = 2

batch_size = 100

iterations = 10000000

x = tf.placeholder("float", name="x")
y = tf.placeholder("float", name="y")

prediction = neural_network_model(x)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=prediction))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for iteration in range(iterations):
    iter_x, iter_y = nextbatch(features, label, batch_size, iteration)
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: iter_x, y: iter_y})

    if iteration % 500 == 0:
        print("Iter:", iteration, "Cost:", c)
        print("Count:", correct.eval({x: val_features, y:val_label})/len(val_label))
```

**EDIT:**

After shuffling the time-series input as suggested by @FlorentinHennecker, the oscillation seems to be reduced.
[image: NN Decision after Shuffling]

Comment: How do you feed the data to your network? Maybe you're showing it a bunch of "Yes" for many iterations then a bunch of "No", making it oscillate like this? 
Also, it's very hard to just think of ways why this behaviour occurs without seeing the code

Comment: @FlorentinHennecker The data are time-series and fed **sequentially** in batches of 100. I'd note that this would sometimes feed it an all "Yes" and all "No" sometimes. I will try to randomize the input batch by shuffling the dataset before hand. Also appended the code.

Comment: Tell us how randomizing went once you tested it :)
I can't directly see anything wrong with the code

Comment: @FlorentinHennecker **Image here:** [link](http://imgur.com/a/cu8HN) Randomizing the input features reduced the oscillation. So it helps alot in term of that. However, the output seems to be random still which I would interpret as the features being uncorrelated or mildly correlated to the output. Would you concur? Or too soon to jump to conclusion?